# Union of Sets Definition

Tags: logic

Definition: A union of two sets A and B is defined as the set of elements which are in A, in B, or in both A and B. I am wondering about the set builder notation of a union of two sets:

$\{x|x\in A\ or\ x\in B\}$

For example, if A = {1, 3, 5, 7} and B = {1, 2, 4, 6, 7} then A ∪ B = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}. This implies that A ∪ B elements consist of both A "and" B, not A "or" B.

Why the use of "or" instead of "and" in the set-builder notation?

Comment: Not from   "point view" of set, but from "point view" of element to be in $A$ **or** $B$ is union.

Comment: Or can be used in two senses: 1) Exclusive or 2) Inclusive or. The one we use in daily conversation is usually the first one (to mean and ) but in mathematics usually or is used in the second sense that is either A or B. So you see that the statement involving logical connective "or"  such as "A or B" is true if at least one of these is true (that is either A is true or B is true).

Comment: So why is $5$ in the union? Which of these statements is true? $$5\in A\text{ and }5\in B$$ $$5\in A\text{ or }5\in B$$

Comment: Correct: "or" for *union* and "and" for *intersection*.

Answer (score 1):

In the builder notation "or" refers to the logical operator. If $x\in A$ or $x\in B$, then $x\in A\cup B$.

That's generally how set builder notation works: you have a formula on the left side, then conditions on the formula on the right. So if you were to describe the set of perfect squares in this notation, you would write $\{x^2|x\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Whenever $x$ is an integer, $x^2$ is in the set.

You can look at it like this:
\begin{align*}
  S = \{x^2|x\in\mathbb{Z}\}\,&\\
  \text{is the same as }\quad x^2\in S \Leftrightarrow x\in\mathbb{Z}&\\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
  A\cup B =\{x|x\in A \text{ or } x\in B\}~~~\,&\\
  \text{is the same as }\quad x\in A\cup B \Leftrightarrow (x\in A \text{ or } x\in B)&
\end{align*}